# Input file not uploading files to server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ecmascript-6

Having issue when i am using fileupload object to show the files while before upload in the modal

Even Try make a shallow copy of DOM object to use it but it still not working 
Kindly Give me a possible solution for this problem

HTML and javascript Kindly see the FileConfigHandler Method

```
        <div id="filedata"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="homepage_contant">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- Start File Upload Section -->
                    <h4>File Upload</h4>
                    <form id="drag-and-drop-zone" class="upload_container" action="/Home/Upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" ondrop="dropHandler(event);">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img class="cloud_upload_img" src="~/Content/images/cloud.png" />
                            <p>Drag &amp; Drop Files Here or <span class="browse_btn_holder">Browse <input class="browse_btn" type="file" accept=".xls..xlsx image/* " multiple id="mfile" name="mfile" title='Click to add Files' /> </span> to upload files</p>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="upload_file_modal modal" id="uploadFileModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="uploadFileModal" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">File Upload</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="container">
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled p-2 d-flex flex-column col" style="padding:0 !important" id="files">
                                                <li class="text-muted text-center empty"><p id="txt"> Files has been seleted. </p></li>

                                            </ul>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="upload_field_wrap">
                                                            <label for="ItemTitle"> File Title</label>
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="upload_field_wrap">

                                                            @Html.DropDownList("Department", ViewBag.lst as SelectList, "Select Department", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="upload_field_wrap">
                                                            <select class="form-control" id="CourseId" name="CourseId">
                                                                <option value="" disabled selected>Course</option>
                                                            </select>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="upload_field_wrap">
                                                            <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
                                                                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
                                                                <option value="mid">
                                                                    Mid Term
                                                                </option>
                                                                <option value="final">
                                                                    Final
                                                                </option>
                                                                <option value="quiz">
                                                                    Quiz
                                                                </option>
                                                                <option value="summary">
                                                                    Summary
                                                                </option>
                                                            </select>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="upload_field_wrap">
                                                            <select id="yearOfPublish" name="yearOfPublish" class="form-control">
                                                                <option value="" disabled> Select Year</option>

                                                                @for (int i = 2000; i < 2020; i++)
                                                                {
                                                                    <option value="@i">@i</option>
                                                                }
                                                            </select>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="upload_field_wrap">
                                                            <label for="description">Description</label>
                                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="" rows="3"></textarea>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>



                    <!-- End File Upload Section -->


@section scripts
{

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dm-uploader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/upload_file_ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        function dropHandler(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            mfile.files = event.dataTransfer.files;
            console.log(mfile);
            //ChangeImageHandler();
            FileConfigHandler();

        }
        function formatBytes(bytes, decimals) {
            if (bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
            var k = 1024,
                dm = decimals <= 0 ? 0 : decimals || 2,
                sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],
                i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
            return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
        }
        function ChangeImageHandler()
        {
            var x = $('#mfile').val();
            let file = $('#mfile')[0].files[0];
            var size = $('#mfile')[0].size;

            var sizeWithTag = formatBytes(size);
            $('#item_size').text(sizeWithTag);
            $('#item_title').text(file.name);
            if (x.split('.').pop()=='pdf') {
                $("#item_type_img").attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/pdf.png");
            }
            else if (x.split('.').pop() == 'docx') {
                $("#item_type_img").attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/doc.png");
            }
            else if (x.split('.').pop() == 'jpg') {
                $("#item_type_img").attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/jpg.png");
            }
            else if (x.split('.').pop() == 'png') {
                $("#item_type_img").attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/png.png");
            }
            else if (x.split('.').pop() == 'ppt') {
                $("#item_type_img").attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/ppt.png");
            }
            else if (x.split('.').pop() == 'txt') {
                $("#item_type_img").attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/txt.png");
            }
            else if (x.split('.').pop() == 'xls') {
                $("#item_type_img").attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/xls.png");
            }
            else if (x.split('.').pop() == 'csv') {
                $("#item_type_img").attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/csv.png");
            }
                console.log();

        }
        function FileConfigHandler()
        {
            console.log('chal raha h')
            var files1 = mfile.files;
            console.log(mfile.files);
            for (var i = 0; i < files1.length; i++) {

               // console.log(files1[i]);
               //var x= AddChild(files1[i]);
              $('#files').append(x);

            }

        }
        function AddChild(item)
        {
            var template = $('#files-template').html();
            var parent = $(template);
            var extention = item.name.split('.').pop();
           // console.log(item.name.split('.').pop());
            var name = item.name;
            var temp_size = item.size;
            var size = formatBytes(temp_size);
          parent.find('#item_size').text(size)
           parent.find('#item_title').text(name)

            if (extention == 'pdf') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/pdf.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'docx') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/doc.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'jpg') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/jpg.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'png') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/png.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'ppt') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/ppt.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'txt') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/txt.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'xls') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/xls.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'csv') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/csv.png");
            }


            return '<li class="uploaded_item">' + parent.html() + '</li>'
        }

        //function dropHandler(ev) {
        //    console.log('File(s) dropped');

        //    // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
        //    ev.preventDefault();
        //    var file = ev.dataTransfer.files;
        //    //  var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        //    var fileData = new FormData();
        //    for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        //        fileData.append("fileData", ev.dataTransfer.files[i]);
        //    }


            //if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
            //    // Use DataTransferItemList interface to access the file(s)
            //    for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
            //        // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
            //        if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
            //            file[i] = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
            //            fileData.append("fileData",ev.dataTransfer.files[i]);
            //            console.log('... file[' + i + '].name = ' + file.name);
            //        }
            //    }


            //} else {
            //    // Use DataTransfer interface to access the file(s)
            //    for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
            //        fileData.append("fileData", ev.dataTransfer.files[i]);
            //        console.log('... file[' + i + '].name = ' + ev.dataTransfer.files[i].name);
            //    }
            //}


        //    $.ajax({
        //        type: "POST",
        //        dataType: "json",
        //        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        //        url:'/Home/SendFile',
        //        contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
        //        processData: false, // Not to process data
        //        data: fileData,
        //        success: function (result, status, xhr) {
        //            alert(result);
        //        },
        //        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        //            alert(status);
        //        }


        //    })
        //}


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#uploadFileModal').hide();
            $('#drag-and-drop-zone').dmUploader({
                onDragEnter: function () {
                    // Happens when dragging something over the DnD area
                    this.addClass('active');
                    $('.upload_container .cloud_upload_img').addClass('animated infinite shake')


                },
                onDragLeave: function (e) {
                    // Happens when dragging something OUT of the DnD area
                    this.removeClass('active');
                    $('.upload_container .cloud_upload_img').removeClass('animated infinite shake');
                    //readmultifiles(document.getElementById('#file'));

                    $('#uploadFileModal').modal("show");




                }})
        })



        $('#mfile').change(function () {

            console.log(mfile.files);
            $('#uploadFileModal').modal("show");
            //document.getElementById("#txt").innerHTML = "1 file has been Selected";
           // console.log(mfile.files);
            //ChangeImageHandler();
            FileConfigHandler();


        });
        $("#Department").change(function () {
            LoadDepartments();
        });

        function LoadDepartments() {
            var collegeId = document.getElementById("Department");
            var ID = collegeId.options[collegeId.selectedIndex].value;
            var depatments = document.getElementById("CourseId");
            console.log(ID);

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("getCourses", "Home")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { idString: ID },
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result)
                    depatments.innerHTML = "";

                    $.each(result, function (i, result) {
                        var options = "<option value='" + result.Id + "' id='" + result.Id + "'>" + result.name + "</option>";

                        $('#CourseId').append(options);
                    });
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
<!-- Debug item template -->
<script type="text/html" id="debug-template">
    <li class="list-group-item text-%%color%%"><strong>%%date%%</strong>: %%message%%</li>
</script>

<!-- File item template -->
<script type="text/template" id="files-template">
    <li class="uploaded_item">
        <div class="item_body">
            <div class="item_img_and_info_holder">
                <div class="item_type_img_holder">
                    <img class="item_type_img" id="item_type_img" src="../../Content/images/files_types/pdf.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="item_info" style="width: 100%">
                    <h6 class="item_title" id="item_title">%%filename%% </h6>
                    <div class="item_details" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                        <span class="item_size" id="item_size">00.0 MB</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

When removing AddChild() from loop it start working
also tried to do shallow copy but it did not work for me

```
  function FileConfigHandler()
        {
            console.log('chal raha h')
            var files1 = mfile.files;
            console.log(mfile.files);
            for (var i = 0; i < files1.length; i++) {

               // console.log(files1[i]);
               //var x= AddChild(files1[i]);
              $('#files').append(x);

            }

        }
        function AddChild(item)
        {
            var template = $('#files-template').html();
            var parent = $(template);
            var extention = item.name.split('.').pop();
           // console.log(item.name.split('.').pop());
            var name = item.name;
            var temp_size = item.size;
            var size = formatBytes(temp_size);
          parent.find('#item_size').text(size)
           parent.find('#item_title').text(name)

            if (extention == 'pdf') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/pdf.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'docx') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/doc.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'jpg') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/jpg.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'png') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/png.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'ppt') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/ppt.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'txt') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/txt.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'xls') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/xls.png");
            }
            else if (extention == 'csv') {
               $(parent).find('.item_type_img').attr("src", "../../Content/images/files_types/csv.png");
            }


            return '<li class="uploaded_item">' + parent.html() + '</li>'
        }
```